# Android Kotlin Billing library 4.0.0 purchase.sku not foud

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-billing

I have updated billing library 4.0.0 and now **purchase.sku** not found so can you help me how to resolved this error in below code.

```
GlobalScope.launch {
                                subsList.forEach { purchase ->
                                    when (purchase.sku) {
                                        SKU_RIFE_MONTHLY,
                                        SKU_RIFE_YEARLY_FLASHSALE,
                                        SKU_RIFE_ADVANCED_MONTHLY,
                                        SKU_RIFE_ADVANCED_YEAR_FLASHSALE,
                                        SKU_RIFE_HIGHER_MONTHLY,
                                        SKU_RIFE_HIGHER_ANNUAL_FLASH_SALE,
                                        QUANTUM_TIER_SUBS_MONTH,
                                        QUANTUM_TIER_SUBS_ANNUAL -> {
                                            albumDao.setNewUnlockedByTierId(true, NewPurchaseActivity.QUANTUM_TIER_ID)
                                        }

                                        HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_WELLNESS_I.sku -> {
                                            albumDao.setNewUnlockedByCategoryId(true, HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_WELLNESS_I.categoryId)
                                        }

                                        HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_WELLNESS_II.sku -> {
                                            albumDao.setNewUnlockedByCategoryId(true, HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_WELLNESS_II.categoryId)
                                        }

                                        HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_WELLNESS_III.sku -> {
                                            albumDao.setNewUnlockedByCategoryId(true, HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_WELLNESS_III.categoryId)
                                        }

                                        HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_LIFE_FORCE.sku -> {
                                            albumDao.setNewUnlockedByCategoryId(true, HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_LIFE_FORCE.categoryId)
                                        }

                                        HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_ABUNDANCE_LUCK.sku -> {
                                            albumDao.setNewUnlockedByCategoryId(true, HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_ABUNDANCE_LUCK.categoryId)
                                        }

                                        HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_ABUNDANCE_SUCCESS.sku -> {
                                            albumDao.setNewUnlockedByCategoryId(true, HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_ABUNDANCE_SUCCESS.categoryId)
                                        }

                                        HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_ABUNDANCE_HAPPINESS.sku -> {
                                            albumDao.setNewUnlockedByCategoryId(true, HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_ABUNDANCE_HAPPINESS.categoryId)
                                        }

                                        HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_ABUNDANCE_LOVE.sku -> {
                                            albumDao.setNewUnlockedByCategoryId(true, HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_ABUNDANCE_LOVE.categoryId)
                                        }

                                        HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_BRAIN.sku -> {
                                            albumDao.setNewUnlockedByCategoryId(true, HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_BRAIN.categoryId)
                                        }

                                        HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_WISDOM.sku -> {
                                            albumDao.setNewUnlockedByCategoryId(true, HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_WISDOM.categoryId)
                                        }

                                        HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_MANIFESTING.sku -> {
                                            albumDao.setNewUnlockedByCategoryId(true, HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_MANIFESTING.categoryId)
                                        }

                                        HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_TRANSFORMATION_MEDITATION.sku -> {
                                            albumDao.setNewUnlockedByCategoryId(true, HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_TRANSFORMATION_MEDITATION.categoryId)
                                        }

                                        HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_PROTECTION.sku -> {
                                            albumDao.setNewUnlockedByCategoryId(true, HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_PROTECTION.categoryId)
                                        }

                                        HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_BEAUTY_I.sku -> {
                                            albumDao.setNewUnlockedByCategoryId(true, HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_BEAUTY_I.categoryId)
                                        }

                                        HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_BEAUTY_II.sku -> {
                                            albumDao.setNewUnlockedByCategoryId(true, HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_BEAUTY_II.categoryId)
                                        }

                                        HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_SKIN_CARE.sku -> {
                                            albumDao.setNewUnlockedByCategoryId(true, HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_SKIN_CARE.categoryId)
                                        }

                                        HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_FITNESS.sku -> {
                                            albumDao.setNewUnlockedByCategoryId(true, HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_FITNESS.categoryId)
                                        }

                                        HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_DMT.sku -> {
                                            //albumDao.setNewUnlockedByCategoryId(true, HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_DMT.Id)
                                            albumDao.setNewUnlockedByCategoryId(true, HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_DMT.categoryId)
                                        }

                                        HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_AYAHUASCA.sku -> {
                                            albumDao.setNewUnlockedByCategoryId(true, HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_AYAHUASCA.categoryId)
                                        }

                                        HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_NAD.sku -> {
                                            albumDao.setNewUnlockedByCategoryId(true, HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_NAD.categoryId)
                                        }

                                        HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_NMN.sku -> {
                                            albumDao.setNewUnlockedByCategoryId(true, HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_NMN.categoryId)
                                        }

                                        HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_DIGITAL_IVM.sku -> {
                                            albumDao.setNewUnlockedByCategoryId(true, HIGHER_QUANTUM_TIER_INAPP_DIGITAL_IVM.categoryId)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```

Comment: I think they changed it to `skus` and then you have to iterate those because now there is the possibility of multiple products bought in a single purchase.

Comment: You have any example @Tenfour04

Comment: No, I skipped to 5. Just kind of guessing. In 5 they aren’t called SKU any more. They never document this library very clearly.